# Observable is not working when app is running in background in ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, observable, publish-subscribe, ionic-native

When I do Login I am starting to check observable working but when application is in background it is not executing. I am using observable because after every 5 seconds refresh should happen. It seems it is not running in background. Any other solution to run the code after every 1 minute whether application is in background or foreground. Thanks in advance !
Loginsuccessfully
    this.provider.startBackgroundRefreshInterval();
In service class below code added

```
startBackgroundRefreshInterval() {
    var refreshInterval = localStore.getPersistedData(App.ISCHECKBOX_KEY);
    this.timerSubscription = Observable.interval(parseInt(refreshInterval))
        .subscribe((val) => {
            console.log("Observable subscribed");
        });
}
 /**
 * unsubscribe subscription
 */
unSubscribeOnehourSubscription() {
    console.log("Observable Unsubscribed");
    this.timerOneHourSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Now refreshInterval is based on checkbox value selection

```
 updateCheckboxList(value:any) {
    this.service.unSubscribeSubscription();
    this.service.startBackgroundRefreshInterval();
  }
```

Once application will go in background Observable not calling 
currently refreshInterval selected as 1 minute

what is other way to call functon continuosly in background in ionic ?

Comment: how to run Observables keep running in Background...

Answer (score 1):

I am currently working on the same thing. While I can't say I know all the things about this, here is what I have found so far.

When your app goes to the background, it is essentially put to sleep.  Meaning none of the code you are counting on, including intervals is going to execute.

Here are some solutions to this problem I have worked on.

1) BackgroundFetch as seen here in this cordova plugin https://github.com/transistorsoft/cordova-plugin-background-fetch and https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-fetch will in both android and ios attempt to run a callback every approximately 15 minutes (read the link for why that timing is a thing).
2) BackgroundMode as seen here https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-mode will put your app into a "stay active while in background" mode that you can control.  This will work in keeping your app up and running even in background, but you may find that this is not acceptable to the stores (particularly might get rejected by ios store).

That's what I've found thus far.  Hope it's helpful.

Comment: Thank you @ccamac

Comment: Right, the Background Fetch wrapper from ionic native says only Ios, but the cordova plugin underneath of it, the thing they are using, that says it works in Android too.  Not sure how that is, but just wanted to point it out.

Comment: I am not sure This is solution of my problem but Thank you for guidance

Comment: ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-background-mode
[WARN] Detected locally installed Ionic CLI, but it's too old--using global CLI.
> cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-background-mode --save
Installing "cordova-plugin-background-mode" for android
warn Error is coming no other option found for me

Comment: @cccamac - No options are working. Can anybody suggest me ?

Comment: Installed Background Mode but after some time interval when app goes in background it is not triggered

Comment: I'm running into similar issues.  be sure to let us know if you find something else.